# Select each nth row in Numbers

Tags: mac, iwork, iwork-numbers

I have an iWork Numbers spreadsheet with thousands of rows. How can I select every 5th row from that spreadsheet?

See also: [Select each nth row in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/69230/select-each-nth-row-in-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In a new column on the first row,
   enter the following formula:

   ```
   =MOD(ROW(), 5)
   ```
2. Copy that cell to every row in the column.
   It should output the remainder of each row number divided by 5
   [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1…].
3. Click the **Sort & Filter** button
   (or select **Table › Show
   Sort & Filter Panel** from the
   menu).

   In the Sort & Filter Panel, check
   the box next to "Show Rows that
   Match the Following." Then select
   the new column that contains the
   formula in the first dropdown, `is` in
   the second, and `0` in the
   textbox.

Comment: This answer was inspired by tpierzina's answer to the same question in Excel. http://superuser.com/questions/69230/select-each-nth-row-in-excel/69232#69232

Comment: Only because VBA macros don't work, otherwise you **so** would have picked my answer. Right? Right? :-)

Comment: I need to explain it to someone who isn't a super user. I figured macros are a little out of reach. I asked this question after figuring out how to do it in Numbers for the sake of curiosity.